# showing a set is not close

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I have this problem which I can't think of function that will show a set is not close.

I would appreciate any help.

Thanks!

$\\$

set $\mathbf X$ as the space of all continuous and bounded functions over the real line, meaning:

$\mathbf{X}=\{f\in C(-\infty,\infty): \forall f, \exists m=m_f, |f(x)| \le m, \forall x \in (-\infty,\infty)\} $

on $\mathbf X$ we will set the supreme norm $\|f\| = \sup_{|x|<\infty}|f(x)| $

let A be the following subset of $\mathbf X$:

$ A = \{ f \in \mathbf X : \exists x_0,f(x_0) = 0\}$

(i.e A is a set of functions from $\mathbf X$ that has any point at which the function get zero)

prove A is not a close set.

hint: find a series $ \{f_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ of functions from A and a function $f \in \mathbf X$  so that $ \lim_{n\to\infty}\|f_n-f\| = 0$ but $ f \notin A$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $g(x)=|x|,$ if $|x|<1$ and $g(x)=1$ if $|x| \ge 1.$ Also let $f(x)=\frac{1}{1+x^2}.$ Define $f_n(x)=g(x-n)f(x).$ Then $\lim_{n \to \infty}||f_n-f||=0$ and each $f_n$ has a zero at $n$ (so is in $A$) but $f$ has no zeros (so is not in $A$).

Note: the sup of $|f_n-f|$ is bounded above by the maximum of $f(x)$ on the interval $[n-1,n+1].$ Clearly the latter goes to zero as $n \to \infty$ because $f$ is asymptotic to the $x$ axis as $x \to \infty.$